# RegEx for capturing the first closing tag in BBCode

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy, bbcode

I have this regex ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HJ58Q3/1/)):

```
\[tag(?:=(["']?)(.+)\1)?\](.*?)\[\/tag\]
```

It allows four different forms:

```
[tag=foo]foo[/tag]
[tag="foo"]foo[/tag]
[tag='foo']foo[/tag]
[tag]sdfo[/tag]
```

All forms works, but if I try to add another `[/tag]` at the end of each form, the first one will continue the catch until the last closing tag (as shown in the linked page). Is it possible to make it not continue the catch, keeping all the forms still valid?

Also, any other suggestion to catch any other strange behavior are accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `.+` non-greedy and it should all work.

`\[tag(?:=(["']?)(.+?)\1)?\](.*?)\[\/tag\]`

Answer (score 2):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/xQ9ta3/1) might help you to capture up to the first desired `[\tag]`:

```
(\[tag?[=A-Za-z0-9\x22\x27]+\])([A-Za-z]+)(\[\/tag\])
```

If you wish to add more boundaries or reduce it, you can do so. For example, you can allow more chars in the `[]`s, if necessary.

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize your expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24). I have added a look behind `g`, as a trick, to pass `[tag]`. That can be also changed, I'm assuming your inputs all have `[tag]`.

[image]

#### Performance

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = '[tag=foo]foo[/tag]foo[/tag]';
 var regex = /^((\[tag?[=A-Za-z0-9\x22\x27]+\])([A-Za-z]+)(\[\/tag\]))(.*)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```